# Is it possible to re-resolve only parent resolves?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

For example if I have an abstract parent state -

```
                abstract: true,
                resolve: {
                    AppData: ['AppDataService',
                      function (AppDataService) {
                          return AppDataService.getData();
                      }
                    ],
                },
```

And child state -

```
                url: '/dashboard',
                resolve: {
                    DashboardData: ['DashboardDataService',
                      function (DashboardDataService) {
                          return DashboardDataService.getData();
                      }
                    ],
                },
```

I can call -

```
$state.reload();
```

But that will re-resolve both parent and child resolves.

Is it possible to re-resolve only the parent resolve?  In this case just AppData?

Comment: I don't think so, but what is your use case for reloading?

Comment: The parent state has multiple named views.  One of those views is a "notifications" style widget that appears on the top menu bar.

Comment: I would like to be able to re-resolve the notifications (data coming from AppData) without re-resolving the child state.

Comment: Each view has a controller - why can't that controller update its own data without reloading the state?

Comment: AppDataService handles data for different things, so there are several controllers.  Notifications, Messages, Tasks.  AppData is resolved from AppDataService.

I have considered injecting AppData and AppDataService into controllers, but because they contain "different" data the controller then needs to decide which one to use.  ie. Should it use the resolved AppData or use the AppDataService to get AppData.

Which is fine but I am trying to avoid repeating that in each controller.

Comment: it's hard for me to understand without understanding your architecture better, but it seems like you don't have good separation of concerns if your `AppDataService` is a monolythic service that you need everywhere. Why not create `NotificationService` that depends on `AppDataService` and inject that into a `NotifcationController`

Comment: The idea of AppDataService is that it calls a single API call that gets some data, rather than many separate API calls.  It isn't needed for every data call, but the data it provides is always displayed.  There is also DashboardDataService for example.

Comment: I quite like the concept of creating additional services that then seperate the single AppData call back out into seperate groups of data.  But how would that help me refresh that data?  Especially if there are now 3 controllers handling that?

Comment: You have a much better overview of your app's architecture, so I can only give high level (and potentially useless) suggestions. However, reloading states to re-resolve value is not a practice I see often (or rather, ever)

Comment: OK thank you.  I will have to think it over.